# Spring mvc data document error : No property execute found for type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, document, autowired

I have entity file `ad.java`:

```
    package com.realestate.data.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Ad {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String city;
    private int price;
    private String phonenumber;
    private int roomnumber;
    private Date dateinsert;
    private Date datepublish;
    private String freedescribetext;

    public String getPhonenumber() {
        return phonenumber;
    }

    public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }

    public void setId(String iD) {
        id = iD;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getRoomnumber() {
        return roomnumber;
    }
    public void setRoomnumber(int roomnumber) {
        this.roomnumber = roomnumber;
    }
    public Date getDateinsert() {
        return dateinsert;
    }
    public void setDateinsert(Date dateinsert) {
        this.dateinsert = dateinsert;
    }
    public Date getDatepublish() {
        return datepublish;
    }
    public void setDatepublish(Date datepublish) {
        this.datepublish = datepublish;
    }
    public String getFreedescribetext() {
        return freedescribetext;
    }
    public void setFreedescribetext(String freedescribetext) {
        this.freedescribetext = freedescribetext;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }


}
```

I also have controller and repository etc.

`AdRepository.java`

```
package com.realestate.data.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.realestate.data.domain.Ad;

public interface AdRepository extends MongoRepository<Ad, String>, MongoOperations {

}
```

`servlet-context.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:property-placeholder
        properties-ref="deployProperties" />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered 
        as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the 
        correct base-package -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.realestate">
        <context:include-filter type="regex"
            expression="com.realestate.*" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Imports datasource configuration -->

    <import resource="../spring-data.xml" />

    <bean id="deployProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/spring/spring.properties" />
</beans>
```

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

the `root-context.xml` is actually empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

</beans>
```

Now I get the error below:

```
`Servlet /ads threw load() exception org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property execute found for type com.realestate.data.domain.Ad`.
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why, but if I change the implements of the repository from

```
public interface AdRepository extends MongoRepository<Ad, String>, MongoOperations{}
```

to

```
public interface AdRepository extends MongoRepository<Ad, String>{}
```

The problem gone.

Maybe `MongoRepository` and `MongoOperations` cause some kind of conflict, I have no idea.